# How to give Format to a text in a String

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, format

I am working on a Android App on Android Studio. The app will show several phrases randomly when a button is pressed.

I already have a simple script for that, using a String variable which contains all the possible texts.

However, I want each text to appear as follows:

"text 1
           - Text1 a"

But I am not able to add the break on the string variable I created.

I currently have it as:

final TextView textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Button motivateYou = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

```
    final String[] misFrases = {"Texto 1", "texto 2", "Texto 3", "Texto 4"};




    motivateYou.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random randGen = new Random();
            final int rando = randGen.nextInt(4);
            textOne.setText(misFrases[rando]);
        }
    });
```

Is this a good way to create the list to add the format?

Or should I add the format on the String file on the res folder and then call the string from there?

As a side comment, I am planning to have lists of 100+ texts

Let me know your comments

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is this:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Text1<br/>next line"));
```

Use Html formatted strings inside of textviews. This should cover most of usecases.

If you want a lot of strings inside of your app, I'd recommnd using an array inside arrays.xml
If you want to port the app to another language, it makes it a lot easier, if you have all strings in one place.
Furthermore you shorten your code inside the Class, since you will have over hundred strings in those lists.